# Getting score null in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{"query":{"bool": {"must": {"match": {"query": ["java"] }}}}}, 
  "sort": {"_timestamp" : "desc"}}
```

executing above query I am getting *max_score* and *_score* is NULL like this

```
 "max_score": null
```

Comment: Can you add your mapping and one sample document?

Answer (score 41):

The reason is because you use custom sorting. Since you need to sort by timestamp, elasticsearch will omit the scoring.

Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html for more.

> If you want the _score to be calculated regardless, you can set the track_scores parameter to true.

Comment: Nice, after setting _**track_scores**_ to *true*, the scores came out. Thank you!

Comment: thanks @Alanight setting the tack_scores worked! :)